# How can I make Siri tolerate longer periods of silence for note dictation?

Tags: siri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to extend the time you can talk to Siri for?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35474/is-there-a-way-to-extend-the-time-you-can-talk-to-siri-for)

I would like to be able to use the note taking feature of Siri to take long dictation for brainstorming ideas. The problem is I find that Siri can only tolerate a second or so of silence and then it thinks I am done and transcribes the note.

Contrast this to the simple dictation feature of Siri that you can find next to the space bar of the keyboard when in the Notes app. There, you can talk as long as you like and pause as long as you like and then it's up to you to hit the done button.

Is there a way to bring Siri up, say the "take note" command, but then only have the dictation stop if the user, say, hits the clicker on the headset?

If not, this pretty much makes Siri useless for taking Notes while driving, because I imagine very few people speak continuously when thinking of ideas.

Comment: Just noticed that someone asked the same question, but there weren't really any clear answers. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35474/is-there-a-way-to-extend-the-time-you-can-talk-to-siri-for