# Is there a way to make Siri listen properly?

Tags: iphone, headphones, siri, voice-dictation

When writing a message using Siri, the software will stop listening for the message at the slightest pause.

For example:

> **Me:** Send a message to John
>
> **Siri:** Okay, what would you like it to say?
>
> **Me:** Hi John...
>
> **Siri:** Okay, your message to John is "Hi John", would you like me to send it?

And this continued every time I left a pause to think what I wanted to say next.

Really annoying. Especially when driving or cycling.

Is there a way to make Siri wait and listen properly?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35474/is-there-a-way-to-extend-the-time-you-can-talk-to-siri-for, but no real answers there...

Comment: Learn to talk to siri differently, she's not human.... "send message to john, hi john i'm on the way"  all one sentence.  just get your thoughts together first and say it all at once, don't have a conversation with her, you will always be displeased with the result.

Comment: @Tyson I'm with you - in fact, I value people that text me actionable bits instead of narratives. The whole "Hi Mike, I was wondering if you had time to" means that they shouldn't have used instant messaging to request something. It's almost like having a robot to teach us when to be to the point is helping (at least some segment of people) us communicate more clearly.

Comment: This is where Dictation in the messages app shines for longer texts.

Comment: "Hi John, um, um, um, um, can you make it to the meeting tomorrow? Um um um..."

Comment: @Tyson You guys are dissecting the content of what she's saying though, not the problem. This same quirk annoys me endlessly. it doesn't have to be "Hi John bla bla..." ANY microscopic pause in the message, even less than one second, "...aand don't forget to" and she'll cut you off. It's very frustrating behavior, and I would give a lot to even have a slightly higher threshold.

Comment: @Cyprus106 never had a problem talking to her personally.  She seems to know when I'm done.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you @Tyson, lucky you don't have that issue. To add some potential symptoms to the issue: I'm a very heavy Siri user and I've got an identical problem to OP and it's only in the "message whomever and say..." command that it will stop on even the most brief pause every single time in every setting. Every other command I can pause for a reasonable amount of time, but the message dictation regularly cuts off my message even with the "pause" in between words for me. No, I don't talk slow, and yes, all other features work as expected.

Comment: @Cyprus106 don't break it into two part, say it all as one sentence.  The point is don't make her ask what message to send include it in the instruction and you'll have better luck

Comment: Again, I do. The problem is within that particular command, no matter what, the most insignificant pause **in** that sentence will cut off your text unexpectedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - Siri currently has no way to program the pauses to detect when you are done speaking. You could have siri open notes and then use the dictation feature to dictate your thoughts with pauses using the keyboard command and then edit them and then finally push that composed thought to messages, but it defeats the ease of using siri to automate the sending of your message.

Without knowing your context (Are you driving and totally hands free? Are you without function of arms/fingers either temporarily or permanently?) it's hard to see if there's a solution to your end goal, but your short term solution is to change the way you interact with Siri to leave less pause. Perhaps just skipping the formality of "Hi John" and just blurt out what you need John to know/do.

Once you've trained yourself to get the main message sent you can work on tacking on "comma thanks so much exclamation point" (or period) or whatever you wish to humanize the main point that's about to be sent.

Comment: Good questions about context: it's for driving and cycling.

Comment: @Baumr Yes - iPhone microphone just doesn't work for me in the car or on the bike. Apple watch somehow works way, way much better - probably the distance of my mouth to the microphone and possibly the hardware is better.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I use the microphone of my Apple Ear Pods when cycling — I think it's more about the software not being clever enough.

Answer (score 14):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to get around this if you want to continue to use Siri from the lock screen or by holding the home button.

Your only solution at the minute is either to make sure you say everything without pausing or enable and use the dictation feature on the keyboard - It listens indefinitely until you tap on 'done' so you will be able to pause to think without getting cut off.

Answer (score 6):

Just continue to hold down the home button (or Siri microphone button) after Siri has been activated and you have started talking.

If you do this, Siri will wait until you let go of the button to process what you have said, so you can make pauses to your heart's content without triggering the "I've stopped" action.

Answer (score -4):

Or u could just go 2 the voice setting and change it 2 never expire, cuz that’s what I did.