# Is it possible to train iMessage dictation to avoid certain errors?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, voice-dictation, spelling

When I dictate, iMessage does not recognize plurals most of the time but creates a possessive instead, even when the grammar is unambiguous. I will say something like "it has useful features" and iMessage will display "it has useful feature's".  Is there any way to train it not to make such errors? Is there a mode that can be turned on that will note any corrections I make to the rendered text?

Comment: Siri is in training to become a greengrocer, it would seem;)

Comment: Yes, it does look as though Siri is taking her cue's from greengrocer's ... or programmer's.  :-)

Comment: I have edited in the siri tag since much of the dictation is foundationally supported by that tech. I wasn’t sure if you are using Messages on a Mac, so an edit on which OS and version would be appropriate if my guess was incorrect. Great question! In the past we had to [train ourselves and not train siri.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/175950/5472)